# Can't Find a Way to Edit the Home Page Content

Tags: php, themes

I'm working on http://www.boldtiger.com and I can't find out how to edit the home page. The previous developer on the project has disappeared, and the site owner and I have had zero luck contact him.

The theme was built custom, it isn't out of the box or even a premium theme. All custom code. There is no actual page for the homepage, and the reading setting is set at current posts.

When i view the source code, I can find what i'm looking for. Specifically, he wants me to change the S1 on the leaderboard to read S3. I can find that S1 in the source code no problem. When i look to the file it calls to edit....index.php....none of that content exists. How do I edit the homepage? Been at this for days, any insight would be a huge help. THANKS!

Comment: What is in your index.php? Any WP_query, get_posts, or query_posts calls?

Comment: Since we're talking about a custom theme without any references to source code, any answers you get here are going to be speculative at best. It could be a hard coded block of markup, a widget, javascript injection, a filter or action, anything really. I'm happy to help if you can provide some source code references.

Answer (score 1):

That's because most probably your theme's `index.php` is including somewhere the content of the template via a function (i.e. `get_template_part()`).
Also, all your page's contents are (and should be) stored in the database and displayed via queries; the contents are not (and they shouldn't be) hard-coded in any file.

Usually when you want to edit a Wordpress page you do it from the admin panel. Open your Dashboard, from the left menu click on "Pages", then click on "All pages", select the page you want to edit (from your website's top menu I'm guessing it's called "Home", maybe?), and click on "Edit". You should see the contents there.