# Unable to find interface that lets me edit text on the front page

Tags: dashboard, editor

I'm trying to edit the text under the "Welcome" and the "A Little About Us" columns of the following website:

http://prnphysicaltherapy.com/

However, under the "pages" button in the dashboard I'm able to view the Home page, but am unable to edit text. Specifically, none of the text viewable on the rendered home page is viewable in the edit interface.

I checked out this question: [Can't Find a Way to Edit the Home Page Content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204211/cant-find-a-way-to-edit-the-home-page-content) which led me to look through the index.php file, but I wasn't able to find it. Does this mean the text I'm looking for is buried somewhere in the "Edit Themes" interface?

Does anyone know what is going on here? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `index.php` is usually not used for the homepage - more often it is `front-page.php`. But just so you're aware, the "Edit Themes" interface is not very secure, and if you edit anything there and later update your theme, all of your edits will be lost. If you need to edit a file, it's safest to create a child theme and upload it using SFTP instead.

Comment: How content is edited on the front page depends *entirely* on your theme. You will need to check it’s documentarion or ask it’s author.